# Fastest route around the world on regularly scheduled transportation?

Tags: air-travel, long-haul, around-the-world, statistics, factoids

After a heated internal discussion about whether it was possible to go around the world within a day (24 hours), I thought I'd ask this question.

Using regularly scheduled flights, it is possible to go around the world.  For example, you could use Air New Zealand to get from [`AKL`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auckland_Airport) to [`LAX`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Los_Angeles_International_Airport), to [`LON`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_Airport_%28disambiguation%29), to [`HKG`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hong_Kong_International_Airport), to [`AKL`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auckland_Airport).

What's the fastest way to use regularly scheduled flights to circumnavigate the world? And yes, I realise it's shorter at lower or higher latitudes, so I'll stipulate you also need to cross at least one of: Tropic of Cancer, Equator, Tropic of Capricorn.

(Transport permitted includes passenger aircraft (not spacecraft, and anything ground/sea-based that takes passengers)

Comment: Some specify that a trip around the world should include two antipode points.

Comment: Phileas Fogg did it in 80 days, but it was back in the times when travelers were not flying :)

Comment: @mithy: Except in hot air balloons.

Comment: Not the fastest route but I think it's cool: http://www.gcmap.com/mapui?P=JFK-JNB-SYD-LAX-JFK.  About 44hours on scheduled flights.

Comment: What do you have against space tourism?!?

Comment: Nothing at all, that's a totally separate question though ;) See our [tag:space] questions :)

Comment: A route that's entirely within the tropics should be allowed as well.

Comment: It is not physically possible to circumnavigate the earth at a terrestrial level in 24 or less hours with in the confines of 23° N/S. The best you can hope for is to learn to levitate and let the world pass you by. Then it will take you just under 24hrs, every time.

Comment: @Ewww note answer below...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Per your specifications, the fastest route "around the world" is [Hong Kong-New York-Hong Kong on Cathay Pacific](http://www.gcmap.com/mapui?P=HKG-NRT-EWR-LHR-HKG&MS=wls&DU=mi), scheduled at 32 hours round-trip.  Approximate routing:

[image]

The flight is non-stop, so London/`LHR` and Narita/`NRT` are there only as (rough) route markers.  While you'd think the route is a straight line (since it's just the "same flight" there and back), due to prevailing wind patterns etc it flies around the North Pole as shown above.  And yes, it crosses the Tropic of Cancer, which is at 23°26′, while Hong Kong is just south of it at 22°16′.

Comment: Anyone who lives in New Jersey will tell you that EWR is not New York... :)

Comment: How did you create this Route image on the Globe? Is there an app/tool?

Comment: @AlexS Click the link: it was created with the Great Circle Mapper (gcmap.com).

Answer (score -1):

I'd say, Singapore Airlines London to Los Angeles Via Singapore then flying back to London by United/Virgin Atlantic.

Comment: Please back this up with data